# Realizar cálculos entre dos df en R

Tags: r, r-dplyr, tidyr

Tengo dos **Data Frame** que quisiera resumir uno a través de un cálculo. Por ejemplo en el nuevo **Data Frame** quisiera tener provincia, anio y valor. En la última columna estarían los valores del cociente entre `vab_min_provincial` y `vab_pb_provincial` para cada año y provincia. ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?.
Los **Data
Frame** son:

```
head(df2_aux)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  provincia              anio  vab_pb_provincial
  <chr>                  <chr>             <dbl>
1 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2004             85707.
2 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2005             93499.
3 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2006            101687.
4 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2007            112152.
5 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2008            117276.
6 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2009            114097.
```

y el siguiente:

```
> head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  provincia              anio  vab_min_provincial
  <chr>                  <chr>              <dbl>
1 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2004                113.
2 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2005                140.
3 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2006                151.
4 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2007                119.
5 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2008                127.
6 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2009                150.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede lograr con dplyr para mejor legibilidad de código. Primero se juntan los dataframes y luego se agrega el cociente deseado así:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("provincia", "anio")) %>% 
  mutate(cociente =  vab_min_provincial / vab_pb_provincial)

               provincia anio vab_pb_provincial vab_min_provincial    cociente
1 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2004             85707                113 0.001318445
2 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2005             93499                140 0.001497342
3 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2006            101687                151 0.001484949
4 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2007            112152                119 0.001061060
5 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2008            117276                127 0.001082916
6 Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires 2009            114097                150 0.001314671
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede resolver de la siguiente forma:

Realizas un merge entre ambas bases con la key para anio y provincia

```
df_aux <- merge(df2, df2_aux, key=c(anio, provincia))
```

luego creas una tercera columna con el cálculo

```
df_aux$calculo <- (df_aux$vab_min_provincial/df_aux$vab_pb_provincial)*100
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
> head(df_aux)
     provincia anio vab_min_provincial vab_pb_provincial   calculo
1 Buenos_Aires 2004           280.2451          131865.8 0.2125229
2 Buenos_Aires 2005           338.8769          144250.3 0.2349227
3 Buenos_Aires 2006           377.4680          154663.0 0.2440583
4 Buenos_Aires 2007           369.3051          165749.0 0.2228099
5 Buenos_Aires 2008           330.2416          173648.6 0.1901781
6 Buenos_Aires 2009           382.9082          162655.5 0.2354106
```

Comment: 1- no es buena idea nombrar a un objeto con el mismo nombre que una función (ejemplo `merge`) y 2- los valores de `vab_pb_provincial` no son los del del `df1`y 3- Lo anterior se debe a que en tu `merge` usaste dos veces `df2` en lugar de usar `df1` y `df2`.